# Jquery toggle makes the container move

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I created a jquery code which lets you click on a button to show or hide a div. However, when I toggle the div the container shifts a bit while it opens. I googled, and everywhere it says the expanding div is losing it's height. How do I fix it? I can't set a height to that div because inside the div I have more expanding content, like little paragraphs where you click "read more" and then more text appears, so the height of the expanding div is always changing.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(
      function ()
      {
        $(".expandbutton").click(
          function ()
          {
            $("#mainexpand").toggle("fast");
          }
        );
      }
    );
</script>
```

So how do I prevent the content from moving around when you click the `.expandbutton` div to toggle the `#mainexpand` div?

Comment: Can you please provide your html?

Comment: <div id="topsection">
<p>In this div there is a lot of stuf blah blah balh</p>
<img src="expandbutton.jpg" class="expandbutton" />
</div>

<div id="mainexpand">
<p>in here is a lot of content</p>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mainexpand").hide();

 $( ".expandbutton" ).click(function() {

  if($("#mainexpand").is(":visible")){
    $("#mainexpand").hide();
  } 
   else {
   $("#mainexpand").show();
  }

 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set visibility instead of displaying or hinding it with display:

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $( ".expandbutton" ).click(function() {
  if($("#mainexpand").css("visibility") == "visible"){
    $("#mainexpand").css("visibility","hidden");
  } else {
   $("#mainexpand").css("visibility","visible");
  }
 });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, however, there is two problems:
1.) on page load it starts on visible, and I want it to be invisible till I click the .expandbutton to show it.
2.) when I click to hide the div, it doesn't make the height of the main site smaller... it just simply hides the content, leaving a large space above my footer.